# jQuery calculation of every row using multiply of quantity and price and display back on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm having an issue when doing some calculation of each table row with the price and quantity. When in the console i can see the result of calculation. But when trying to display back on table it duplicate all the total sum of first row into all rows.

Here is the sample code for the part of calculation and the table display.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://ayambrand-com-my-v1.cloudaccess.host/index.php?option=com_echarity&format=raw&task=api.get_product_name",
    data: {dataArrayPost : Data},
    success: function(data){
        // console.log('Result process get product name' + data);
        var a = JSON.parse(data);
        // console.log('Result from get_product_name');
        // console.log(a);
        var prodName = a.productName; 
        var splitProductName = "";
        var prodQty = a.quota; 
        var splitProductQuota = "";
        var prodPrice = a.price;
        var splitProductPrice = "";
        var discountedPrice = "";

        
        var contents = '<table id="tableDonateDisplay" class="table table-hover">';
        contents += "<tr>";
        contents += '<th>' + 'Product' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Quantity Need' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Price Each' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'My Donation' + '</th>' + '<th>' + 'Amount' + '</th>';
        jQuery.each(prodName, function(index1, value1) {
            // console.log(prodName);
            splitProductName = value1;
            contents += "<tr>";
            contents += '<td>' + splitProductName;
            jQuery.each(prodQty, function(index, value) {
                if (index1 == index) {
                    splitProductQuota = value;
                    contents += '</td><td>' + splitProductQuota;
                    jQuery.each(prodPrice, function(index2, value2){
                        jQuery.each(value2, function(index3, value3){
                            if(index == index2){
                                splitProductPrice = value3.price_value_with_tax.toFixed(2);
                                // console.log(splitProductPrice);
                                var formQuantityUpdate = "<div class='amount-controller' data-module='amount-controller'><span id='qtyminus' field='quantity' class='handle'><i class='fas fa-minus-square'></i></span><input class='input-num' type='text' id='num[]' name='number' value='0'><span id='qtyplus' field='quantity' class='handle qtyPlusHandle'><i class='fas fa-plus-square'></i></span><input type='hidden' id='pricePerProduct' name='priceHidden' value='" + splitProductPrice +"'><input type='hidden' id='maxQuantity' name='maxQuantity' value='" + splitProductQuota +"'></div>";
                                
                                contents += '</td><td>' + 'RM ' + splitProductPrice + '</td>';
                                contents += '<td>' + formQuantityUpdate + '</td>' + '<td>' + '' + '</td>' + '<td class="eachSum">' + '' + '</td>';
                                contents += "</tr>";
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        contents += "</tr></table>";
        if (jQuery('#contentNeed').html()) {
            jQuery( "#contentNeed" ).empty();
        }
        else {
        }

        jQuery('#contentNeed').append(contents);
    }
});
```

Here is the part for calculation and quantity plus minus input. The quantity will stop when it reach the quantity limits for each items.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var counterTotal = 0;
    var quantity = 0;
    var maxQuantity = 0;

    jQuery(document).on('click','#qtyplus',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fieldName = jQuery(this).attr('field');
        var container = jQuery(this).parents('.amount-controller');
        var currentVal = parseInt(container.children(".input-num").val());
        var priceVal = parseFloat(container.children("#pricePerProduct").val());
        var totalPriceCont = jQuery('.eachSum');
        // totalPriceCont = jQuery('#eachSum');
        maxQuantity = parseInt(container.children("#maxQuantity").val());
        var val2 = currentVal + 1;
        if (!isNaN(val2)) {
            container.children(".input-num").val(val2);
        } else {
            container.children(".input-num").val(0);
        }
        quantity = val2;
        if(quantity > maxQuantity){
            quantity = maxQuantity;
            container.children(".input-num").val(quantity);
            return false;
        }
        else{
            console.log('Quantity Plus :' + quantity);
            counterTotal = priceVal * quantity;
            totalEach = counterTotal.toFixed(2);
            console.log('Sum Total Price Qty Plus : ' + totalEach);
            totalPriceCont.html(parseInt(totalEach));
        }
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '#qtyminus', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        fieldName = jQuery(this).attr('field');

        var container = jQuery(this).parents('.amount-controller');
        var currentVal = parseInt(container.children(".input-num").val());
        var priceVal = parseFloat(container.children("#pricePerProduct").val());
        var totalPriceCont = jQuery('.eachSum');
        // console.log(priceVal);
        var val3 = currentVal - 1;

        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            container.children(".input-num").val(currentVal - 1);
        } else {
            container.children(".input-num").val(0);
        }
        quantity = val3;
        console.log('Quantity Minus :' + quantity);
        console.log(currentVal);
        counterTotal = priceVal * quantity;
        totalEach = counterTotal.toFixed(2);
        console.log('Sum Total Price Qty Minus : ' + totalEach);
        totalPriceCont.html(parseInt(totalEach));
    }); 
    // totalPriceCont.html(parseInt(totalEach));
});
```

Results:

[image: Results]

What am I doing wrong and how do I do this correctly?

Comment: Could you please add working snippet which can show your problem ?

Comment: Aside:: As far as I can tell, `a.productName`, `a.quota` and `a.price` are congruent arrays. If so, then `a.productName[index]`, `a.quota[index]` and `a.price[index]` contain corresponding values and the nested `jQuery.each()` loops and tests `if(index_ = index__)` can disappear.

Comment: Aside:: HTML ids should be unique. Where you build `formQuantityUpdate`, use classes not ids (and adjust the javascript accordingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initiating 'totalPriceCont' object like this:

```
var totalPriceCont = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('.eachSum');
```

Comment: It works. It update each row. First time using .closest. Thanks @Karan Patel. Anyone want to know more detail about .closest may refer https://api.jquery.com/closest/